# How change color of a selected item?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a collection view, where each of item is selected with the same brown color, this is my item

[image]

this is my code:

```
<CollectionView SelectionMode="Single"  ItemsSource="{Binding CeLLs}">
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackLayout>
          <Label TextColor="Black"  background="Black"/>
```

i want to change the color brown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#change-selected-item-color), there is a section shows you how to change color of a selected item.

CollectionView has a Selected [VisualState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualstate) that can be used to initiate a visual change to the selected item in the CollectionView:

In your case, change the `backgroundColor` of `stacklayout` would work:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                    Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<CollectionView SelectionMode="Single">
    <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
            <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
            <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </CollectionView.ItemsSource>

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="Black"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>

    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

</CollectionView>
```

Another way is binding the BackgroundColor with the property in your ViewModel and change it when the item is [selected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.selectableitemsview.selectionchanged):

```
 <Label Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="{Binding backColor}"/>
```